# Need advice on building a "subscription" service in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, publish-subscribe

I am building an application for students at my school to let users stay up-to-date with our learning management service (Canvas) while on platforms like Facebook Messenger and Slack.

As of now, I have a decent amount done, but I am working on the Node service that will go through each user in the DB, look at their "subscribed" courses, and check Canvas to see if any updates, like new assignments, have been posted for those courses. At a high level, my thoughts are that this would just be a `setInterval(function() {...}, TIME_INTERVAL)` that would do what I described above.

I am able to connect to Canvas, and have taken some time to search through their APIs, and it doesn't seem like they offer webhooks I could use.

Does the solution I have, just running all of this logic in a `setInterval(...)`, seem like the right way to solve this problem? Or are there any more elegant solutions that I am not aware of?

Comment: What do you need the `setInterval` for? Why don't you have an app that run just once and cron the app by creating a crontab file? The operating system would do much better job in scheduling your app for you.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks for the suggestion! That seems like a better solution than setInterval

Comment: see http://socket.io/

Comment: @Jekk I'm familiar with socket.io but I'm not sure how it would simplify my problem. It seems like I would still need to constantly poll Canvas to see if new assignments were posted, then I could emit events